# Under Langlands duality, which semisimple Lie groups are self-dual?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, duality-theorems, root-systems

Consider a semisimple Lie group $G$. We define the Langlands dual $\hat{G}$ of $G$ as the group which has as a root system, the root system generated by the coroots of $G$. Recall that given a root $\alpha$, its coroot is defined by 
$$\hat{\alpha}=2\dfrac{\alpha}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$$

Now I wonder, which groups are self-dual?

I could work the exercise for any group, just computing the coroot system.
However I was wondering if there is an easier way to state which group is L-dual to which other, and if it is self-Langlands-dual. Does it exist a reference with a list of the couples of dual groups?

Comment: Actually, you are misstating definition of Langlands dual: You also have to change the fundamental group (in most cases) since you are required to swap characters and cocharacters  as well. Of course, weight lattice sometimes equals the root lattice and then the Lie algebra determines everything.

Answer (score 5):

The Langlands dual group is defined for *reductive* groups, not only for semisimple Lie groups. For example, $SL(n)$ is dual to $PGL(n)$, $SO(2n+1)$ is dual to $Sp(n)$ and $SO(2n)$ is self-dual. The group $GL(n)$ is self-dual, too.
Passing to the level of Lie algebras, the Langlands duality changes the types of simple factors of the Lie algebra by taking the transpose of the corresponding Cartan matrices. 
For a reference see J.W. Cogdell's article [Dual groups and Langlands Functoriality](https://people.math.osu.edu/cogdell.1/jerusalem-3-www.ps), section $1$ and table $1$.